# How to trace all endpoints or methods with OpenTelemetry and manual configuring

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I'm trying to use OpenTelemetry SDK to trace my java application. When I'm using [auto configuration](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/) with opentelemetry-javaagent.jar I see a lot of methods traced. But when I'm using [manual config](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/manual/) I need to add spans for all methods I want to trace. How I can trace all methods and just filter some unnecessary ones with manual config?

Comment: check out the OTel "standalone library instrumentations": https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/supported-libraries.md#libraries--frameworks